# Blurry picture on external vga monitor using Linux (openSUSE 13.2)

Tags: linux, resolution, xrandr

I have Acer Aspire 5610 laptop (quite old I know). I'm running openSUSE 13.2. When I connect external monitor Acer V243H, which has native resolution 1920x1080 the picture gets blurry.

Doing some research I found about the xrandr utility. I tried:

```
:~> xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 800, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1280x800      60.00*+
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   640x480       59.94
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x800      59.81
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      70.07    60.00
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   640x480       66.67    60.00
   720x400       70.08
```

Monitor does support native resolution. I manually added this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -
HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

The picture just gets blurry (I can't see anything). I also tried with KDE 4 -> systemsettings -> Display And Monitor but no change. I also ran dmesg command which printed next error:

```
[drm:i9xx_set_fifo_underrun_reporting] *ERROR* pipe A underrun
[drm:i915_irq_handler] *ERROR* pipe A underrun
```

Maybe this is the reason why outputing to external monitor does not work. **Note: resolution lower than 1920x1080 works ok.** If I run:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768
```

the picture shows on external monitor just fine.

Funny thing is that I tried installing Microsoft Windows XP and output to external monitor works ok (native resolution 1920x1080). So, hardware is ok. Anybody have any idea how to fix this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was unable to set my VGA connected monitor to it's native resolution because of corrupted EDID information. I have summarized my solution in a kind of tutorial:
http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1948
Try if it helps.

Comment: It is best to post the answer here. One day the link may go stale.